# Physiology Software / non-ragdoll graphics

Tags: graphics, vector, physics, physics-engine

I'm looking for a program that can describe force vectors acting on the human body. Does anyone know of such a program?

***Example:** someone is pushed straight back on the right front shoulder. How does the force act on the clavicle, the spine, the hips, the right knee, the right foot?*

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [inverse kinematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_kinematics), which is concerned with calculating the angles & orientations of joints given the desired position of a hand or foot.  Not quite the same, but related to what you're after.